# Is it appropriate to use exports while defining a brand new module in require.js?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

Since require.js is AMD module loader, while defining a new module like:

```
define(["jquery"],function($){
   var _private;
   var obj = {
       pubFunc:...
   }
   return obj;
});
```

or

```
define(["jquery","exports"],function($,exports){
 var pubFunc;
 exports.pubFunc = pubFunc;

});
```

Is it the second is inappropriate in Require.js's defining new module?

Comment: Are you asking if the second form is _possible_? Or if it's _recommended_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** the first is how RequireJS has been designed to work (use that one); the second isn't.

**More info:**

It looks like you're confusing RequireJS with Node's require.

In the second, you're almost reversing the direction of the dependency-chain by exporting backwards (into what should be a dependency).

This will actually work most of the time:

```
exports.pubFunc = pubFunc;
```

insofar that:

- JavaScript Objects are passed by reference, so the property will be added to the `exports` Object held by RequireJS; and
- RequireJS will continue to distribute the modified `exports` Object whenever `exports` is required.

However, this is entirely reliant on RequireJS's caching.  As an optimisation, RequireJS stores modules' exports, rather than loading the file every time; hence the cached version of `exports` is redistributed (complete with the property you added).

Consequently, this would break when the cached Object is not passed around, such as in different RequireJS [contexts](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-context).

You should be treating imports as immutable, even if you can modify them.